POST API call using Power Query M/PBI
Hope all is well! Im using Power BI Desktop and Im trying to connect to data via an API POST request. Im going through Power Query M to gather the data but fairly new at it.
My query looks like the below (XXXX are replacing passwords/sensitivity) but I get the following error message:
Query Image:
Power Query M script
Query:
let
url = "XXXX",
body = "{
""limit"": 1000,
""projection"": ""XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX"",
""group"": ""XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX""
          }",
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, [Headers=[#"Content-Type"="application/json", #"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"="XXXX", Authorization="XXXX"]]))

in
Source
Error Message:
Expression.Error: The 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' header is only supported when connecting anonymously. These headers can be used with all authentication types: Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Cache-Control, Content-Type, If-Modified-Since, Prefer, Range, Referer
Error Message Image
Error Message
Im I not entering the right query to run? How can I connect anonymously? Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!
I tried the below and want to get access to the data. Not sure if my script is right or I need additional steps in it:
let
url = "XXXX",
body = "{
""limit"": 1000,
""projection"": ""XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX"",
""group"": ""XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX""
          }",
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, [Headers=[#"Content-Type"="application/json", #"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"="XXXX", Authorization="XXXX"]]))

in
Source

Try clicking on "Data source settings" in the ribbon, select the connection, Edit Permissions..., then Edit under Credentials and ensure it is set to Anonymous.

Depending on the Software of the Data source and the auth requirements there.
since you are using passwords.
Check their API Doc to make sure that the way you're accessing it is correct, otherwise you will need to use a supported data connection in PowerBi or a 3rd party step like an SQL, Azure DB, etc
If you're positive you can access the data anonymously then:
File > Options and settings > Data source settings, selecting your data source, and then Edit Permissions.
Authentication method > Anonymous
